# Could not connect to port 5222 in ejabberd hosted in local windows machine:

Tags: android, windows, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I have installed ejabberd in windows 10 and I want my android application(running in android device in same network) to login to the locally hosted ejabberd server.

Note: I could access ejabberd admin portal in port 5280 ie. [192.168.x.x:5280/admin] from the android device but couldn't connect to port 5222.

Code for **XMPPTCPConnection** :

```
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        builder.setXmppDomain("192.168.x.x");
        builder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        builder.setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password");
        builder.setResource("smack");

        XMPPTCPConnection mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(builder.build());
```

I get the following error:

```
 I/DNSUtil: Could not resolve DNS SRV resource records for _xmpp-client._tcp.192.168.x.x. Consider adding those. W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException:   The following addresses failed: '_xmpp-client._tcp.192.168.x.x:5222' failed because: de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException:    Asking for _xmpp-client._tcp.192.168.x.x.   IN  SRV yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN, '192.168.x.x:5222' failed because: de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException:     Asking for 192.168.x.x. IN  A yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN, '192.168.x.x:5222' failed because: de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException:   Asking for 192.168.x.x. IN  AAAA yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN
```

I have also modified the **ejabberd.yml** file in order to listen to all the ipv4 ports as described in [ejabberd documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#port-number-ip-address-and-transport-protocol)

```
listen:
- 
port: 5222
ip: "0.0.0.0" 
module: ejabberd_c2s
starttls: true
certfile: 'CERTFILE'
protocol_options: 'TLSOPTS'
max_stanza_size: 65536
shaper: c2s_shaper
access: c2s
-
port: 5269
ip: "0.0.0.0"
module: ejabberd_s2s_in
max_stanza_size: 131072
shaper: s2s_shaper
- 
port: 5280
ip: "0.0.0.0"
module: ejabberd_http
request_handlers:
  "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
  "/api": mod_http_api
web_admin: true
http_bind: true
## register: true
captcha: false
```

Any work around is highly appreciated.

Comment: xmpp domain should be a valid host, not an IP